# The 'name' doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a C#, ASP.NET website, and I've encountered a problem. It's also using a SQL database for inserting purposes. What I'm experiencing is when I attempt to write code either in the aspx file using "code here" or in code-behind i.e "page.aspx.cs", I still encounter this same problem.

So, I've create a project as a "Web Form", and it includes the "Register/Identity" module, and I'm working on the "Register.aspx" page to add extra fields that I require, and on click to register I'm attempting to insert them into a different database.

```
<script runat="server">
 protected void Unnamed20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Users"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql;
        sql = "insert users (username, title, gname, sname, dob, address, suburb, state, postcode, phone, email) values (@Username, @Title, @Gname, @Sname, @Dob, @Address, @Suburb, @State, @Postcode, @Phone, @Email)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Prepare();

        String suburb = txtSuburb.Text;


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", RegisterUser.UserName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text);

    }
```

Now the problem occurs where it says '@Title', txtTitle.Text "txtTitle.Text" is the problem, so for me It's called txtTitle.Text in my web page but when I'm trying to access it via code as above it gives me the error of this posts title. It comes up underlined in red, and I don't know how to fix this problem.

Here is the markup for the `txtTitle` control:

```
<li>
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Title">Title</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTitle" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</li>
```

How can I fix this so I'm able to access these controls via code?

Comment: Can you show the markup for `txtTitle` control?

Comment: ` <li>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Title">Title</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTitle" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </li>`

Comment: That should be an edit to the post, not the comment. Also, is it within a template of some kind? Like update panel, or grid view, or anything like that?

Comment: Sorry, and no it's just inside the standard "CreateUserWizard#RegisterUser" html area

Answer (score 0):

As turned out in the comments, `txtTitle` control lives inside the wizard control. Such controls cannot be accessed directly, so you need to make use of `FindControl`:

```
TextBox txtTitle = (TextBox)WizardControlIdHere.StepNameHere
                                               .ContentTemplateContainer
                                               .FindControl("txtTitle");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text);
```